# To perform a task when timer is running

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, timer

Please help me, i have created a timer and I want to perform a specific task when my timer is running. but my code is not allowing me to run the task when timer is running. It only sleeps when timer is running. my code is

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<sys/time.h>
#include<signal.h>
#include <time.h>
#define INTERVAL 10


void timerhandler(int signum)
{

printf("\ni m manoj doing some specila task\n");

}

int timer()
{
    int i;
    struct itimerval val;
    struct sigaction action;

    sigemptyset(&action.sa_mask);
    action.sa_handler=&timerhandler;
    action.sa_flags=SA_RESTART;
    if(sigaction(SIGALRM,&action,NULL)==-1)
    {   
        perror("sigaction");
        return 1;
    }


    val.it_interval.tv_sec  = 0;
    val.it_interval.tv_usec = 0;
    val.it_value.tv_sec = 3;
    val.it_value.tv_usec    = 0;

    if(setitimer(ITIMER_REAL,&val,0)==-1)

        perror("alarm");



    else 

    for(;;)
    {
    Sleep(10);
    printf("timer val is  %d", &val.it_value.tv_sec );
    printf("\ni m manoj doing normal task\n");

    return 0;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
timer();
}
```

Comment: You should use parallelism, maybe this can help you:http://www.cs.grinnell.edu/~walker/c/concurrency/intro.pdf

Comment: Are you saying that "printf("\ni m manoj doing some specila task\n");" doesn't execute?